# Try to get bitRate, sampleRate,channelCount

Tags: java, android, audio, sample-rate

i want to get bitRate, sampleRate,channelCount of one audio file

i use code

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void  GetSampleRate(String path)
    {
        MediaExtractor mex = new MediaExtractor();
        try {
            mex.setDataSource(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());// the adresss location of the sound on sdcard.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MediaFormat mf = mex.getTrackFormat(0);

          bitRate = mf.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE);
          sampleRate = mf.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_SAMPLE_RATE);
          channelCount = mf.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CHANNEL_COUNT);

    }
```

But when compiler come on this line

```
mex.setDataSource(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());
```

logcat show one error

```
10-13 12:57:52.772: E/WVMExtractor(9554): Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not found
```

and then this error when i try to get bitRate, sampleRate,channelCount.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to open libwvm.so: dlopen failed: library "libwvm.so" not
>   found

means that device where you are running your code has not that library. You could try to compile your own version of `libwvm.so` and bring it in. With the exception thrown, `mex.getTrackFormat(0);` is returning a null reference and `mf.getInteger(` is making your app crash for `NPE`. To avoid the crash you could return after printing the stacktrace of the exception. E.g.

```
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks For Reply. But how can i get libwvm.so i search for this but couldn't found anything

Comment: But running DRM Info on my Moto G5 does say that Widevine CDM is there. Also, getTrackFormat(0) etc. all work perfectly. Yet I still have this error.